# Android Kindle Fire - Make standard app or tablet?

Tags: java, android, kindle-fire

Since Kindle Fire is not on HoneyComb, should I just build a standard app for the Kindle Fire? I have made multiple Android phone apps, but never a tablet app.  But it appears to me that Kindle won't use things like fragments?

What considerations should I take in designing an app FOR the Kindle Fire outside of what I already know in designing phone apps?

I read the Amazon docs, but couldn't really find any specific development info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are in the [Android Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). From a technological standpoint, a tablet app is just an app. You just make use of the larger screen real estate. You can get started in the usual Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, since I've yet to get a Fire for testing, but I'm supposing that you can use Android's ["Support Package"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to use fragments since it's Gingerbread.